# Erratic output when accessing cells in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe of character strings that includes `NA`'s. Here is an altered subpart of it:

```
subdf
            Col1                Col2
1           <NA>                <NA>
2 Other Services                <NA>
3 Other Services                <NA>
4 Other Services Services of lawyers
5 Other Services                <NA>
```

I want to replace the `NA`'s depending on the cell value to their left/right. I tried to do this the following way:

```
subdf$Col1[subdf$Col2=="Services of lawyers"]

[1] NA               NA              
[3] NA               "Other Services"
[5] NA
```

As apparen, I get erratic outputs when looking up the `NA` cell. This makes it impossible to adequately replace the appropriate `NA` value.

`na.omit()` is obviously not applicable, since I am expecting `NA` as output in order to replace it.

Comment: You will need to post a sample of the data frame that is giving you the error, not an example that has no error.

Comment: You example would make sense if there would be an NA in row 4 in Col1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You could use `which` around your logical test to remove the unexpected `NA` results of the subsetting operation:

```r
subdf$Col1[which(subdf$Col2=="Services of lawyers")]
```

---

**Explanation**

I think we can replicate your issue like this. Suppose I have a data frame with no `NA` values:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C"), y = 1:3)
```

If we want to find the values of column y when x == "A", we do:

```r
df1$y[df1$x == "A"]
#> [1] 1
```

This gives us the expected result. But look what happens when there are `NA` values in `x`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", NA), y = 1:3)
```

What result would you expect now?

```r
df2$y[df2$x == "A"]
#> [1]  1 NA
```

This might seem unexpected. After all, we only wanted the values of y when x was "A", but now we have a length-2 result, which neither matches the length of the data frame *nor* the number of "A"s in our data frame. Why?

It is because we are subsetting by the logical vector `df2$x == "A"`, which is:

```
df2$x == "A"
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE    NA
```

So if we subset by this, we will get the first item selected, the second item omitted, but the third item isn't omitted. If you subset by `NA`, an `NA` is returned. That is why we get two items returned.

The simple way to suppress this is to wrap your logical test in `which`, since it will convert to numeric indices and quietly drop `NA` values:

```
df2$y[which(df2$x == "A")]
#> [1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
table <- data.frame("Col1"=c(NA, "B", "C"), "Col2"=c("A'", "B'", "C'"))
table %>% 
  mutate(
  Col1 = ifelse(is.na(Col1), stringr::str_extract(Col2, "[A-Z]+"), Col1)
)
```

Edit for new data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(~Col1, ~Col2, 
        "<NA>", "<NA>",
        "Other Services", "<NA>",
        "Other Services", "<NA>",
        "<NA>", "Services of lawyers",
        "Other Services", "<NA>"    
        ) 

df%>% 
  mutate(
    Col1 = ifelse(Col1 == "<NA>", Col2, Col1)
  )
```